# How to cache a Guzzle Http request?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, cache, guzzle

In my module I have the following:

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => myBaseUri]);

$response = $client->request('GET', myQueryString, [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept'            => 'application/json',
        'Accept-Encoding'   => 'deflate,gzip'
    ],
    'connect_timeout' => 3,
    'verify' => false,
    'timeout' => 5,
    'http_errors' => false
]);

$json = $response->getBody();
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

How can I cache this so it only does the request every 5 minutes?

Comment: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/craft-cacheservice.html#public-properties

craft()->cache->set('some_key', 'some_value', 3600);

Comment: @JimWyse this is v2, couldn't see this in v3??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either cache it globally or in the session

```php
// your cache key
$key = 'akey';

$cache = Craft::$app->getCache();
$value = $cache->get($key);
// check if there is a valid value that is not older than 5 minutes
if ($value !== null && \is_array($value) && isset($value['time']) &&
    $value['time'] >= time() - 3600) {
    return $value['value'];
}

// make your request
$response = Craft::createGuzzleClient(['base_uri' => $myBaseUri])
    ->get('GET', myQueryString, [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept'            => 'application/json',
        'Accept-Encoding'   => 'deflate,gzip'
    ],
    'connect_timeout' => 3,
    'verify' => false,
    'timeout' => 5,
    'http_errors' => false
]);

$json = $response->getBody();
$data = Json::decode($json, true);

// cache it
$cache->set($key,  
    'time'  => time(),
    'value' => $data
]);
```